# Using method attributes to eliminate redundant code

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I have the following method which prints lines to the console.

```
public void MyMethod() {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        Console.WriteLine("My name is MyMethod");
    }
    finally {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye.");
    }
}
```

I have a few of these methods and they all do the same thing (i.e. try { "Hello"; Something; } finally { "Bye." }). To avoid redundancy and make my code clearer, I came up with the following:

```
public void SayHello(Action myName) {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        myName();
    }
    finally {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye.");
    }
}

public void MyMethod2() {
    SayHello(() => Console.WriteLine("My name is MyMethod"));
}
```

I like this technique, but I think it could be even better by using an attribute. Here is what I would like to ultimately achieve:

```
[SayHello]
public void MyMethod2() {
    Console.WriteLine("My name is MyMethod");
}
```

It would be great if I could simply add a method attribute to help me eliminate redundancy (i.e. try { "Hello"; Something; } finally { "Bye." }). Is it possible in C# to create such attribute?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. Attributes should decorate code, not generate it, otherwise it is not really clear what the code is doing. I would simply try subclassing.

Comment: I'd say that the method you're using right now pretty clearly expresses the goal of the code while providing the capability you're looking for, whereas writing it using an attribute is confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) techniques, specifically [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Vote this up:

"CompileTimeAttribute to inject code at compile time"
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=93682

Comment: Note to editors: "Vote this up" is in reference to the "CompileTimeAttribute to inject code at compile time" on microsoft connect.